# AWS single session OR multiple sessions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I am creating an application in Golang hosted on AWS cloud, that uses multiple AWS services i.e. S3, DynamoDB, Parameter Store.

Currently Individual modules handing each AWS service has their own AWS session.

```
awsSession, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(os.Getenv("AWS_REGION"))})
```

From performance perspective, is this a correct way, or having a single session created in the main program and passing the reference to individual module will be a better approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's recommended to reuse the session if possible.

From the AWS Go SDK [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/session/):

> Sessions should be cached when possible, because **creating a new
>   Session will load all configuration values from the environment, and
>   config files each time the Session is created.** Sharing the Session
>   value across all of your service clients will ensure the configuration
>   is loaded the fewest number of times possible.